# How to combine FFMPEG commands of multiple RTSP to HLS

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some of cameras with different RTSP url and I want to convert all of them from RTSP to HLS so as to show on my website. I'm using single command in Command prompt for each camera now.
Example:
`ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.2:554/Streaming/Channels/101" -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 10 "camera1.m3u8"`
`ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.2:554/Streaming/Channels/201" -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 10 "camera2.m3u8"`
`ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.2:554/Streaming/Channels/301" -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 10 "camera3.m3u8"`

I must run 3 commands in 3 Command prompt. Can I combine multiple commands into single command?